# how can i concat first_name and last_name two different database fields to assign to drop down list in cakephp using 'list' in find statement

Tags: cakephp

```
$swimmer = $this->Swimmer->find('list', array(
    'conditions' => array('Swimmer.group' => $this->data['Swimmer']['group_id']),
    'order' => array('Swimmer.first_name ASC'),
    'fields' => 'Swimmer.first_name'
));
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First of all, setup a [virtual field](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1588/virtualFields) in your Swimmer model as suggested by Ann Pham. eg:

```
var $virtualFields = array(
    'name' => "CONCAT(Swimmer.first_name, ' ', Swimmer.last_name)"
);
```

Then, fetch the data for your dropdown list like so: (assuming Swimmers controller)

```
$this->Swimmer->find('list', array('fields' => array('Swimmer.id', 'Swimmer.name')));
```

---

You could also try doing this in your SwimmerModel:  `var $displayName = 'Swimmer.name';` (not 100% sure if this would work). If it does work, you won't need the 'fields' array in the find.

Comment: SQL Error: 1054: Unknown column 'Swimmer.name' in 'field list' 

Query: SELECT `Swimmer`.`id`, `Swimmer`.`name` FROM `swimmers` AS `Swimmer` WHERE 1 = 1

Answer (score 1):

An another approach is to concat the field on the fly in the fields list.

Ex:

```
$swimmer = $this->Swimmer->find('list',
array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'Swimmer.group' => $this->data['Swimmer']['group_id']),
    'order' => array(
        'Swimmer.first_name ASC'
    ),
    'fields' => 'CONCAT(Swimmer.first_name, " ", Swimmer.first_name) AS full_name'
));
```

Answer (score 0):

http://book.cakephp.org/view/1588/virtualFields